# Kernighan and Ritchie C exercise 1-16

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I tried to implement a solution for the exercise on the C language of K&R's book. I wanted to ask here if this could be considered a legal "solution", just modifying the `main` without changing things inside external functions.

> Revise the main routine of the longest-line program so it will
> correctly print the length of arbitrary long input lines, and as much
> as possible of the text.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 2 ////

int get_line1(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && ((c = getchar()) != EOF) && c != '\n'; i++) {
        s[i] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    int len;
    int max = MAXLINE;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    int tot = 0;
    int text_l = 0;

    while ((len = get_line1(line, max)) > 0) {
        if (line[len - 1] != '\n') {
            tot = tot + len;
        }
        if (line[1] == '\n' || line[0] == '\n') {
            printf("%d\n", tot + 1);
            text_l = text_l + (tot + 1);
            tot = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", text_l);
}
```

The idea is to set the max lenght of the string considered for the array `line` ad 2.
For a string as `abcdef\n` , the array `line` will be `ab`. Since the last element of the array is not `\n` (thus the line we are considering is not over), we save the length up until now and repeat the cycle. We will get then the array made of `cd`, then `ef` and at the end we will get the array of just `\n`. Then the `else if` condition is executed, since the first element of this array is`\n`, and we print the `tot` length obtained from the previous additions. We add +1 in order to also consider the new character `\n`. This works also for odd strings: with `abcdefg\n` the process will go on up until we reach `g\n` and the sum is done correctly.

Outside the loop then we print the total amount of text.

Is this a correct way to do the exercise?

Comment: Each solution that fulfills the requirements is equally correct.

Answer (score 2):

The exercise says to “Revise the main routine,” but you altered the definition of `MAXLINE`, which is outside of `main`, so that is not a valid solution.

Also, your code does not have the `copy` or `getline` routines of the original. Your `get_line1` appears to be identical except for the name. However, a correction solution would use identical source code except for the code inside `main`.

Additionally, the exercise says to print “as much as possible of the text.” That is unclearly stated, but I expect it means to keep a buffer of `MAXLINE` characters (with `MAXLINE` at its original value of 1000) and use it to print the first `MAXLINE`−1 characters of the longest line.